# Application item not working for Interactive grid

Tags: oracle-apex

In my application, i have application item that stores employee id.
I have a form where emp_id=application item id and an interactive grid which also has application item in where clause.

In form, the application item value is available and shows as emp_id.
But in interactive grid it doesn't .

Form P1_emp_id =:APP_ID -> Displays emp_id = 1
IG : emp_id = :APP_ID -> emp_id is null.
It doesn't take the application item value although it is there in the session.

Answer (score 1):

Did you try to give '*submit*' or '*return item*' values? Maybe you should add the item there and it will take the value. Or try 'fire on initialization: yes' and put the page on 'after refresh'. If none of them works then please provide us more detailt to solve this problem, thanks.